# boostrap responsive nav border

Tags: bootstrap-4, border, responsive, nav

I'm using bootstrap to build a responsive nav bar, I'm triying to remove the border of the nav but I cant find a way to do it.
here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
     </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is because the default css for the **navbar** class in bootstrap 3.3.7 includes a **border-radius** rule. You should check this answer, it might help you to remove it: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35451590/2726490